# Se puede crear una app en ionic pero sin tenerla que subir a la appstore?

Tags: ionic, ios, app

Soy nuevo en la creación de aplicaciones móviles para iOS, elegí Ionic por recomendación de un amigo, la app que estoy desarrollando es para mi trabajo, osea, es una app privada y no cualquiera la puede descargar, mi duda es, se puede crear una app para iOS sin necesitad de subirla a la appstore?

Answer (score 2):

Claro que sí, despues de relizar tu app y compilar se guardará como un archivo en el caso de android .apk
Sí tu lo deseas debes de subir ese ejecutable en playstore.
Pero si no simplemente puedes compartir el archivo por otros medios.

Comment: muchas gracias, tenia esa duda